# Single SSO in WSO2 API store fails with Google IDP

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS(5.3.0) and WSO2 APIM(2.1.0).I have configured  **API_Store** as service provider using **SAML** protocol  for authentication using Identity-Server using Single Sign On. I have configured google as Identity Provider with SAML protocol for federated login. When i access the API store it redirects me to Identity-Server page with multiple login option like local authentication or with  Google [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Lf8V.png) .
When i click on Google IDP it redirects me to Google login Page. After entering the credentials of user it redirects me to logout page [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIaHX.png). Meanwhile when i access the API-store on different tab the user is already logged in API Store.

Could anyone tell me why the request is not redirected to API_STORE home page after entering the user credentials for google or if i am missing some configurations.

Comment: Did you configure callback URL property? What did you set?

Comment: Hi @Bee I have entered https://<AM-ip>:<port>/store/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag in service provider as Attribute consumer URL for SAML protocol

Comment: Hi is their any solution for the same as i am stuck in between and couln't proceed further

Comment: Is it possible to attach the network trace... only the urls will be fine..

Comment: Hi @Thanuja , sorry but due to security concerns i can't attach the URLs